# Can fly CLI tool be used for any Concourse machine?

Tags: continuous-integration, concourse

Im working with Concourse and using the fly cli tool.  When I create any new VM or instance running Concourse it will immediately give me the option to download the fly cli tool.

Is this version of fly specific only to the machine I downloaded it from or will it work on any machine running Concourse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fly` will warn you its version is too different from the target, and prevent itself from running if the discrepancy is too large (a major or minor version difference), in which case you should run `fly sync`.

If it's not warning you, you should be fine.

Comment: Also if your fly version is out of sync with the concourse machine your using it will tell you exactly what sync command to use.  For example when using the vagrant VM it tells you to run `fly -t lite sync`